# Magento 2 checkout bad request

Tags: magento2, checkout

For the past 2 days, I haven't had any sales because Magento checkout is not processing my orders. It's giving me this error: "An error occurred on the server."

Error 400 While Receiving The Response From Payment Information.

Image error:
https://scontent.fgdl2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.30808-6/350119154_730127159120672_7714966606860123206_n.jpg?_nc_cat=100&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=5cd70e&_nc_eui2=AeGIQ7qut0H7gWEEgB9N7Mm3q_y6kDPom-6r_LqQM-ib7mb0NDVjXdmecKYS4jdqmjw&_nc_ohc=543G_33ZIqwAX-LcVCn&_nc_ht=scontent.fgdl2-1.fna&oh=00_AfCWOHKtzf-FAxRm1QRwj6qC2hSJ59mdvhfIOb9i7bxr1w&oe=6478A642

Has anyone experienced this issue before and knows how to resolve it, or has any ideas on how I could find a solution?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The error generated from `\Magento\Checkout\Model\GuestPaymentInformationManagement::savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder`. You can see error details on system.log and exception.log at var/log folder of your project

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.

I have activated error logs with this command:
`bin/magento setup:config:set —enable-debug-logging=true`
`php bin/magento cache:flush`

but nothing is showing, also i have check the logs, in the log directory, and nothing.

Comment: This is my system.log
https://cloudup.com/cNw1N4n-5u0

Comment: Now is working, there was an error conexion
public_html/app/etc/env.php

with the 'queue' => [ 'amqp' => [

Answer (score 1):

Now is working, there was an error conexion `public_html/app/etc/env.php`

with the `'queue' => [ 'amqp' => [`

Answer (score 0):

I read the topic and went through the answers and found that you are getting the error:

`'queue' => [ 'amqp' => [`

I think the current workaround is that you open the `env.php` file at the `app/etc` path.

Make sure the `amqp` configuration is correctly defined.

Then clear the cache with the following command: `php bin/magento cache:clean`

Hope it helps you to solve your problem.